# Преобразовать json текст в объект C#

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api, http, парсер

Делаю программу которая работает с vk api. Отправляю http запрос, получаю ответ, кладу его в строковую переменную. Вопрос: **как преобразовать json строку в объект ?**

По коду примерно так:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?post_id=95825848&owner_id=-13295252&count=2");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{

    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    // MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer, "Текст");
}
else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error 404");
}
response.Close();
```

Comment: Например, при помощи Json.NET: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Answer (score 1):

`vkClass vk=JavaScriptSerializer ().Deserialize<vkClass> (responseFromServer)`
`vkClass`можно сгенерировать [online](http://json2csharp.com/)